# Mongoid complex ploymorphic relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, mongoid, polymorphic-associations

I would like to set up a set of relationships that look something like the code below
the main thing I think my problem is in the SomethingThatNeedsAnAnswer Class where I want to have a relationship with the polymorphic model using a name that is different than its class name

```
Class Votable
   has_many :votes
   belongs_to :question, polymorphic: true
end
Class Vote
   belongs_to :selected_answer, polymorphic: true
   belongs_to :votable
end
Class SomethingThatNeedsAFewAnswers
   has_one :some_question, class_name: "Votable", as :question
   has_one :some_other_question, class_name: "Votable", as :question
end
Class ExampleAnswerClass
    field :some_text_field
    has_many: votes: as :selected_answers
end
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my models were not really the issue, the issue was with the test for these modles which I still can seem to get right, but the code I thought I was asking about is actually functional